# PHP - Internal 500 error in function

Tags: php

i'm getting 500 internal error in this script for some reason i looked trough the script for like an hour or two cant find the issue in the function, its not an mysql error ether..

```
    function CreateGame($Game, $Pass, $Diff, $CharInfo, $Lad, $Desc, $Realm, $Hash, $timestamp, $Bot = 0)
    {
        $uno = false;
        include "conf.php";
        $conn = new mysqli($serverip, $username, $password, $dbname, $Port);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . encrypt($conn->connect_error);
        } 
        $game = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $Game);
        $pass = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $Pass);
        $diff = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $Diff);
        $hash = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $Hash);
        $charInfo = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $CharInfo);
        $desc = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $Desc);
        $realm = substr($Realm, 0, 1);
        $realm = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $Realm);
        $bot = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $Bot);
        $lad = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $Lad);
        $UserResult = $conn->query("SELECT * from user where hash = '$hash'");
        if (!$UserResult) 
        {
            echo encrypt("hash not found: ". $hash);
        }
        while($row = $UserResult->fetch_assoc()) 
        {
            if($uno == false)
            {
                $uno = true;
                $BanCheckQuerrt = "SELECT * from hwid where id = '".$row['HWID']."'";
                $BanCheckResult = $conn->query($BanCheckQuerrt);
                while($BanCheckRow = $BanCheckResult->fetch_assoc()) 
                {
                    if((int)$BanCheckRow['banned'] === 0)
                    {
                        $sql = "INSERT INTO games (Game, Password, Description, Difficulty, Realm, Ladder, BotGame, created, timestamp ) VALUES ('$game', '$pass', '$desc', '$diff', '$realm', 'lad', '$bot', '$timestamp', '$timestamp')";
                        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                            $sqli = "INSERT INTO Players (GameID, Name, timestamp) Values ('".mysqli_insert_id($conn)."', '$charInfo', '$timestamp')";
                            if ($conn->query($sqli) === TRUE) {
                                $updateUserQuerry = "UPDATE user SET playerID = '" .mysqli_insert_id($conn). "' where hash = '$hash'";
                                $conn->query($updateUserQuerry);
                                echo encrypt(mysqli_insert_id($conn));
                            } else {
                                echo "Error: " . $sqli . "\n" . encrypt($conn->error);
                            }
                        } else {
                            echo "Error: " . $sql . "\n" . encrypt($conn->error);
                        }
                    }
                    else
                        echo encrypt("Banned!");
                }
            }
        }
        $conn->close();
    }
```

any suggestion that would fix this problem would be acceptably.

Comment: Can you provide us the error message?

Comment: its just internal error 500 nothing more, i even checked the logs nothing there

Comment: This `mysqli_escape_string($conn, $Game);` is procedural style you are using object style. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: If you are only getting an HTTP 500 and nothing from PHP then it sounds like PHP errors are off.  Place this at the top of your script to have PHP spit out whatever errors it is encountering: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I guess you'll have to learn how to debug php...http://php.net/manual/en/debugger.php

Comment: @Crackertastic thanks it looked like i missed a ) in die syntax :)

Comment: @Gunzmo Good deal, glad that helped..  Having PHP kick out its errors can help during development and testing of your code.  Make sure you turn it back off when you are ready to use it in your production environment.